# Postgres Upsert vs Truncate and Insert

Tags: postgresql, insert, upsert

I have a stream of data that I can replay any time to reload data into a Postgres table. Lets say I have millions of rows in my table and I add a new column. Now I can replay that stream of data to map a key in the data to the column name that I have just added.

The two options I have are:

1) `Truncate` and then `Insert`

2) `Upsert`

Which would be a better option in terms of performance?

Comment: truncate/insert would be faster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way PostgreSQL does multiversioning, every update creates a new row version. The old row version will have to be reclaimed later.

This means extra work and tables with a lot of empty space in them.

On the other hand, `TRUNCATE` just throws away the old table, which is very fast.

You can gain extra performance by using `COPY` instead of `INSERT` to load bigger amounts of data.